Before Trigger on User also firing as an After Update Event
I have a before trigger on user which checks if a checkbox is selected and assign a manager if user's team matches another user's.
The issue is that the trigger should only run on before insert or before update, but it's also getting triggered on after update (This is evident from the log screenshot below). This is the only trigger or automation that I have in the system for user but it fires an after Update and gives error 'Record is read-only'.
trigger UserTrigger on User (before insert, before update) {
    if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isUpdate) {
        System.debug('this line should not be logged');
        return;
    }
    List<User> users = new List<User>();
    Set<String> teams = new Set<String>();
    for(User u: trigger.new) {
        if(u.Assign_Manager__c == true && (trigger.isInsert || trigger.oldMap.get(u.id).Assign_Manager__c) != u.Assign_Manager__c) {
            users.add(u);
            teams.add(u.Team__c);
        }
    }
    
    List<User> managers = [Select Id, Team__c, ManagerId from User where team__C in: teams];
    
    for(User u: users) {
        boolean managerFound = false;
        for(User u2: managers) {
            if(u.Team__c == u2.Team__c && u.Id != u2.Id) {
                u.ManagerId = u2.id;
                managerFound = true;
            }
        }
        if(!managerFound) {
            u.addError('Manager not found for user: ' + u.Id);
            return;
        }
    }
}



That's certainly disconcerting. As a sanity check, can you double check this trigger of yours in the dev console in the same org that you got that log from to verify that this isn't just an issue of a code update not being deployed to the org?

It's a fresh developer edition org that I am using for learning purposes. I don't think that's the case.

@soumyakhandelwal Are you using VS Code for your deployments? If so, copy paste the code you posted in the trigger using Dev Console and try again. I highly doubt that this is Salesforce bug.
